# Truncate strings in an array which match a particular format, then filter out unaltered elements

Tags: php, arrays, loops, filtering, explode

I have an array which is a mix of strings that I want to keep and strings that I don't want to keep.  Of the strings to keep, I need to truncate them from their first occurring slash.

My array:

```
$code = [
    'PO/2022/0001',  // modify
    'abc',           // remove
    'xyz',           // remove
    'PO2022/0001',   // remove
    'XY/2022/0002',  // modify
    'PO/2022/0232'   // modify
];
```

I am trying to `explode` the strings in the above array on `/` and if the newly generated array has 3 elements, then I need to push the first value into my result array.

Expected result from sample input:

```
['PO', 'XY', 'PO']
```

Can I know what is the better and efficient approach to do this?

This is what I have so far:

```
foreach ($code as $v) {
    $nwCode = explode("/",$v);
    if(count($nwCode) == 3) {
      $nwAry[] = $newCode[0];
    }
    
    $nwCode = [];
}

echo '<pre>',print_r ($nwAry).'</pre>';
```

Comment: fyi, you can use [`count()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) to check the `explode` result length. then you could use `if` to check if its contains 3 items or not, and finally `array_push` the result to accumulator or something. well, you could try to use `array_map` too if you want to drop the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$code = ['PO/2022/0001', 'abc','xyz','PO2022/0001', 'XY/2022/0002','PO/2022/0232'];

$prefixes = array_map(function($e){
  $nwCode = explode('/', $e);
  if(count($nwCode) == 3)
  {
    return $nwCode[0];
  }
} ,$code);

$prefixes = array_filter($prefixes, function($e){ if(strlen($e) > 0) return true; });

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($prefixes);
echo "</pre>";
```

The [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) used to get those prefixes, while [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty prefixes from the unmatching items.

You could use [`array_reduce`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) too.

```
$prefixes = array_reduce($code, function($carry, $item){
  $nwCode = explode('/', $item);
  if(count($nwCode) == 3)
  {
    array_push($carry, $nwCode[0]);
  }
  return $carry;
}, array());
```

Comment: One thing, do I use `count($nwCode) > 2)` or `count($nwCode) == 3)`

Comment: @TharangaNuwan, `count($nwCode) > 2` will return `true` if your `$nwCode` has at least 3 items in it. you could use `count($nwCode) == 3` for exact match. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to perform replacements on strings with a strict format/signature AND filter out elements that do not match the signature, the best tool that PHP has to offer is `preg_filter()`.

Pattern breakdown:

```
^              #start of string
[^/]+          #one or more non-slash characters
\K             #forget/release previously matched characters
(?:/[^/]+){2}  #match 2 sets of slash followed by one or more non-slash characters
$              #end of string
```

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/NjX8q))

```
var_export(
    preg_filter(
        '~^[^/]+\K(?:/[^/]+){2}$~',
        '',
        $code
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'PO',
  4 => 'XY',
  5 => 'PO',
)
```

IF you require indexed keys, call `array_values()` on the result array.